# Adding and Removing div when a checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a table with a list of exercises like so:

```
<table class="table table-image" id="exercise_table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr class="bg-hercules-font">
                        <!-- Image -->
                        <th scope="col">Exercise Name</th>

                        <!-- Name -->
                        <th scope="col">Body Part</th>

                        <!-- Plan -->
                        <th scope="col">Select</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="checkBox">
                      <tr>
                        <td>Bench Press</td>
                        <td>Chest</td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="checkkk">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checktest" value="option1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checktest"></label>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>Incline Bench Press</td>
                        <td>Chest</td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checktest" value="option1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checktest"></label>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>Ab Roll Outs</td>
                        <td>Abs</td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checktest" value="option1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checktest"></label>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>Cable Crunches</td>
                        <td>Abs</td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checktest" value="option1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="checktest"></label>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>

                  </table>
```

There is a column for checkbox. My goal is that when this box is checked I want an arrow icon to appear, to do this I have used a script:

```
$('.checkBox :checkbox').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        //If the box is checked
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {

          //The arrow we are going to insert
          var newInput = $('<a href="index.php" id="next_page"><span style="color:#43425D;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-lg"></i></span></a>');

          //Insert the div into the "here" class
          $('#here').append(newInput);

          //If not, we remove the arrow
        } else {
          $('#here').find('#next_page').remove();
        }
      });
```

When the box is checked the arrow icon will be appended in this div:

```
 <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4" id="here">
   <a href="add_workout.php" id="link"><h3 class="h4 mb-0 text-gray-800">Cancel</h3></a>

 </div>
```

The problem is that for every checkbox i click the arrow will appear again. So, if i click 2 boxes for example, then 2 arrow will appear instead of only one. What can I do to make it so everytime I click a box the arrow will only appear once and if no box is clicked then the arrow will not appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one idea would be to check all checkboxes everytime you check/uncheck and then decide if arrow should stay or not. I have better idea... Just keep track of how many checkboxes are checked. When there is only 1 checkbox(at least but why swap everytime) then create arrow if there is 0 checkboxes checked then only then remove arrow. Example with `html()` instead of `append()`

```
var checked_counter = 0;
$('.checkBox :checkbox').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);


    //If the box is checked
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
       checked_counter = checked_counter + 1;
    }else{
       checked_counter = checked_counter -1;
    }

     if(checked_counter == 1){

           //The arrow we are going to insert
           var newInput = '<a href="index.php" id="next_page"><span style="color:#43425D;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-lg"></i></span></a>';

          //Insert the div into the "here" class
          $('#for-my-arrow').html(newInput);

          //If not, we remove the arrow

     } else if(checked_counter == 0) {
      $('#for-my-arrow').find('#next_page').remove();
     }

     });
```

html

```
 <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4" id="here">
       <a href="add_workout.php" id="link"><h3 class="h4 mb-0 text-gray-800">Cancel</h3></a>
       <div id="for-my-arrow"></div>      
 </div>
```

Comment: @simple I deleted previous answer because we started conversation there and answer was becoming confusing.

Comment: I tried this and the arrow has gone missing I dont know why

Comment: This works. Finally :D Do u mind explaining the difference between `html` and `append`?

Comment: Do you understand why it works ? You have to learn reading docs because as a programmer you will spend there lot of time :D. https://api.jquery.com/html/
`html()` will change everything inside, `append()` will append element after what is inside of particular element. https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content